# Load one fragment in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that has more than 10 fragment, but all are in fixed orientation which is portrait, but in that one fragment is required to load in landscape mode, it look like that fragment is in landscape can i do that?

That fragment, in that i want to load in landscape, **is webview, in that i am loading youtube page.**

I did not find proper answer in anywhere would you help me how to do that thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `FrameLayout` in the xml layout in `layout-land/your_activity.xml` only.
Then in `onCreate` if `findViewById` returns not null for that layout you put a fragment in there using `FragmentManager.replace`

Answer (score 1):

You can not really change the orienation properties of the fragment that it is bounded to the parent activity so when the activity is change its orientation then its child orientation properties will change it as well.

**solution:**

You can have a flag that check if you want it portStyle or landStlye;

So each time you create the fragment you then pass a data bundle to it to set its flag to landStyle and you can then use a landscape layout for the fragment if landStyle is set to true.

```
onCreateView()
 if(landStyle)
  //inflate the layout as landscape
 else
  //inflate the layout as portrait
```

Comment: Sorry @Rod but please chk my question again, that was i have updated

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit no can go even if it is webView, but you can still design the webview as a landscape and use that as the layout.

Comment: sorry because it is loading youtube page, i want to load full page youtube video

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit then make the webview match the parent, if it doesnt fit you cant really do about it.